# ExoPlayer HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a playlist of 7 dash(.mpd) videos. I'm using Exoplayer version 2.8.4. Exoplayer is stuck in loading for the last two of them and I'm getting the following error in my logs. Other 5 videos plays seamlessly. What could be the reason. Thanks in advance.

Logs:

```
11:41:39.322 31189-31221/com.example.exoplayercodelab E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

In my eventListner's onPlayerError, this is the stackTrace of the error :

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137)
   at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Are you sure the last 2 link are available ?